# CSS - Want an SVG Arrow to be 1/2 Inside and 1/2 Outside of Parent Container (Can't Figure Out How)

Tags: css

Here's what I'm trying to do:

[image]

Here's how it is now:

[image]

Current CSS:

```
.left-icon {
  position: absolute;
  top: 150px;
  left: 203px;
}

.drawer-arrow { 
  overflow: visible; 
  z-index: 1000; 
}
```

I have the element setup like this:

```
<span className="left-icon"> 
      <img className="drawer-arrow" src={DrawerArrowOpen} /> 
</span>
```

Comment: Can you share the HTML that your browser sees after the script has finished running? Right-click -> inspect element -> right-click in the inspector -> select 'copy' -> 'copy outerHTML'.

Answer (score 1):

Apologies, I figured out the problem / solution - it was in no way related to the basic CSS ...

So apologies for leading everyone on a wild goose chase here...

It was a material UI component that the arrows were within.

I resolved by pulling the arrows outside of the component and layering them ontop of the actual component, so that the arrows weren't bound by the position set within the material UI component.

OLD COMPONENT:

```
    const drawer = (
        <div>
            <div className={"sidebar"}>
                <div className="logo-wrapper">{logoHtml}</div>
                  {
                    matches && (
                        <div
                            onClick={() => {
                                setSidebarOpened(!isSidebarOpened);
                            }}
                            style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                        >
                            {isSidebarOpened ? (
                                <span className="arrow-left-icon">
                                    <img className="drawer-arrow" src={DrawerArrowOpen} alt="Drawer Arrow Open" />
                                </span>
                            ) : (
                                <span className="arrow-right-icon">
                                    <img className="drawer-arrow" src={DrawerArrowClosed} alt="Drawer Arrow Closed" />
                                </span>
                            )}
                        </div>
                )}
                <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
                    <MapRoutesToPageLinks
                        navRoutes={navRoutes}
                        isSidebarOpened={isSidebarOpened}
                    />
                </Accordion>
            </div>
        </div>
```

NEW COMPONENT(S):

```
    const arrowIcons = (
        <div className="arrow-icons">
        {
            matches && (
                <div
                    onClick={() => {
                        setSidebarOpened(!isSidebarOpened);
                    }}
                    style={{ cursor: "pointer" }}
                >
                    {isSidebarOpened ? (
                        <span className="arrow-left-icon">
                            <img className="drawer-arrow" src={DrawerArrowOpen} alt="Drawer Arrow Open" />
                        </span>
                    ) : (
                        <span className="arrow-right-icon">
                            <img className="drawer-arrow" src={DrawerArrowClosed} alt="Drawer Arrow Closed" />
                        </span>
                    )}
                </div>
        )}
        </div>
    );


    const drawer = (
        <div>
            <div className={"sidebar"}>
                <div className="logo-wrapper">{logoHtml}</div>
                <Accordion defaultActiveKey="0">
                    <MapRoutesToPageLinks
                        navRoutes={navRoutes}
                        isSidebarOpened={isSidebarOpened}
                    />
                </Accordion>
            </div>
        </div>
```

Then I put the `arrowIcons` outside of the drawer in the render -

[image]

Answer (score 0):

did you try to add a Z-index to your icon ?

```css
.left-icon { 
    position: absolute;
    top: 150px;
    left: 203px;
    color: white;
    z-index: 1;
}
```

Comment: I have the element setup like this `<span className="left-icon" <img className="drawer-arrow" src={DrawerArrowOpen} /> </span>` with CSS for `.drawer-arrow { overflow: visible; z-index: 1000; }`

Comment: Can you create a sandbox ? It would be easier to debug https://codesandbox.io/

Comment: Here you go. I tried to strip out a lot of the noise, as there is a lot more to the app - https://codesandbox.io/s/quirky-euler-ulbce4?file=/src/components/Sidebar/index.js

Comment: ugh, i see the issue now that it's in code sanbox, there is an overflow on the container so it scrolls to the right and the full arrow is actually shown when you scroll... Didn't see that on my local env. Still trying to figure out where that's coming from though.

Comment: Looks like it's some div from material UI  that has `position: fixed` - haven't fixed out the solution yet, but I'm pretty sure I've got it from here. Thanks for the help!